# Compact operator takes weakly convergent sequence to strongly convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, compact-operators

I was reading Compact Operator from the functional analysis Book by Erwin Kryszig. There I find that if $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ in a Banach space $X$, then for a compact operator $T$, $Tx_n \to Tx_0$. An important portion of the proof consists of the fact that $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx_0$.

Now, my question is, can we prove the same assertion, without using the fact that $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx_0$?

A detailed answer will be of very much help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t know, but I think that is the most natural thing to do. In principle, it would actually suffice to prove that whenever $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ and $Tx_n\to y$, then $Tx=y$ (I don’t know how the proof that you mention goes, but I am pretty sure it uses Urhyson convergence criterion). But at the moment, the most natural thing that I have in mind to prove that is again to prove $Tx_n\rightharpoonup Tx$ XD

Comment: Curiosity: is there a specific reason for you to ask this question?

Comment: Actually, I am expecting a topological proof with out using functional@LorenzoPompili

Comment: Ok, I see. Try to prove that T is continuous from X equipped with the weak topology to Y equipped with the usual topology (i.e. prove that the preimage of an open ball in Y is weakly open in X). That should be enough

Comment: Thankyou@LorenzoPompili for this piece of information.

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote is not correct. In Brezis, Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDEs, exercise 6.7, it is stated that the property that I wrote is true only for finite rank operators. So there is no hope that you prove that for a general compact operator

Comment: If we can show that $T$ is weak to weak continuous, then can we conclude the same?@LorenzoPompili

Comment: No. If I am not wrong, weak-weak is equivalent to strong-strong. It was stated somewhere in the book by Brezis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128454/discussion-between-user490489-and-lorenzo-pompili).